# What's your strategy for collecting Solr metrics?

Tags: search, solr, lucene, full-text-search

Is there any open source tools for this? Something with pretty graphs maybe? Or is all we have in /admin/stats.jsp?

I am looking for monitoring tools, search metrics mining, and log analysis.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I´ve been looking into this and there are a few alternatives. What first comes to mind is a Lucid Imagination product called [**Lucid Gaze**](http://www.lucidimagination.com/downloads). I know it was free to download and use but I cant find it anywhere on their page anymore. I´ts probably still around though.

Otherwise since the application is running inside a JVM you can always do standard Java VM monitoring which is what I usually do. I use [**JVisualVM**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) to debug how the Solr server behaves but there is a flora of tools out there.

If you have a larger clustered installation I would look at log mining tools such as 
[**Splunk**](http://www.splunk.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Not open source, but might want to check [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/).

http://www.cmswire.com/cms/web-cms/new-relic-offers-lucene-and-solr-performance-monitoring-007719.php
http://blog.newrelic.com/2010/05/11/got-apache-solr-search-server-use-rpm-to-monitor-troubleshoot-and-tune-solr-operations/

Answer (score 1):

Solr can provide lots of information with its regular components, and I doubt there's any external tool that can cover all Solr features. I suggest you looking at the following components:

- [LukeRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler) - index browser
- [StatsComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/StatsComponent) - simple statistics for indexed numeric fields
- [TermsComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent) - term frequency statistics (note, that you can find even more statistics about frequency of terms with faceted search)

Answer (score 1):

The new Solr Admin page (Solr 4.x) has some new stats - JVM, memory, and a few more.  No long-term/timeseries trending, but useful.  All Solr stats are exposed via JMX.  Not free, but better than NewRelic mentioned above is [SPM for Solr](http://sematext.com/spm) from Sematext.

Solr logs are not terribly rich if you want to mine them.  They do contain the search query and query latency, but that's about it.  What you want to collect besides queries is the clickstream.  I know of no open-source tool for this, but [Search Analytics](http://sematext.com/search-analytics) (free, also from Sematext) does a good job of capturing queries and clicks and mining that to provide a set of useful reports about search metrics.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for extracting Solr metrics via the Solr MBean API (replaces /stats.jsp for Solr 4.x) with optional threshold support for alerting:

check_solr_metrics.pl

Find it here:

https://github.com/harisekhon/nagios-plugins

This is for Nagios compatible monitoring systems (combine with PNP4Nagios or similar for auto-graphing the perfdata).

Comment: Welcome to SO, and thanks for answering! Not that you don't need to sign your posts, as it is automatically done for you (with a link to your profile and hence your linkedin account).